# Preferring compile-time constants to enums in some specific cases

Tags: java, enums

I'm reading J.Bloch's Effective Java and come up with the following (Setcion about enums):

> Far fewer enums benefit from associating multiple behaviors with a
>   single method. In this relatively rare case, prefer constant-specific
>   methods to enums that switch on their own values

To me this case of using compile-time constants is not clear. Couldn't you provide a simple example reflecting that?

Comment: The last bit should probably say "**methods** that switch on **`this`**", or something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what is being discussed in that passage is the comparison between:

```
void myMethod(MyEnum enum){
    switch(enum){
    case VALUE1:
        break;
    case VALUE2:
        break;
    }
}
```

and

```
enum MyEnum{
VALUE1(){
    protected void myMethod(){
        //body
    }
},
VALUE2(){
    protected void myMethod(){
        //body
    }
}
protected abstract void myMethod();
}
```

Comment: So, he meant by constant-specifiec method was just a method contaning a switch-case?

Comment: @St.Antario No, a constant-specific method is one of the methods in the second code block.

Comment: It seems, I got it. Bloch said erlier in the section that if an enum was not under our control we should prefer switching on the enum's values. Is my understanding correct now?